# Redirect all pages to one page on another website

Tags: redirect, server

I want to redirect 301 all pages of a old website to a subpage of another/new website.

for example

- domain.com/page-1
- domain.com/page-2
- and lot more...

should all redirected to

new-domain.net/page-generel

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .htaccess file and place the following code in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://new-domain.net/page-general [R=permanent,L]
```

**UPDATE**
also you need to enable mod_rewrite in apache if not already enabled.
Reference to enable mod_rewrite in ubuntu:
http://www.iasptk.com/enable-apache-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/
For centOS:
https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/

Comment: This doesnt work. If I open one of the old urls, the new url looks like:

new-domain.net/page-general/page-1 ... so it combines the new and old url.